# Radial Basis Function Library

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, octave

I'm looking for a Machine Learning library capable of classifying with radial basis function networks (for homework). Preferentially in Python, but Matlab/Octave is also acceptable.

I looked at PyML, PyBrain, scikit-learn and mlpy but couldn't find it in any of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here'a a matlab FEX option for [Radial Basis Function Network](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22173-radial-basis-function-network), and [an older code from Mark Orr](http://www.anc.ed.ac.uk/rbf/).